# Width & Height Fluid Design

Tags: css

http://www.juliabailey.com/

This website has fluid design and it's working very nicely.

http://goo.gl/j6snn

This is my website. Fluid view is depending on width. Therefore, when I get my browser bigger width gets bigger as well as height. But the problem is height is too big and creating scrollbar which I don't want. I don't what scrollbar to appear on my page. I think the best way would be fluid view depending on height so it always fits in browser no matter your browser is 800x600 or 1600x1200. How can I do it ?

Here is my wrapper code;

```
#wrapper {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    width:80%;
    min-width:550px;
    max-width:1150px;
    margin:50px auto 0 auto;
    z-index:100;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use percentages for the properties of your classes.  for example:

```
wrapper {
width: 92%;
}
content {
width: 73%;
}
sidebar {
width: 25%
}
```

type thing OR

you can also use javascript to detect what you need and then change the implementation dynamically.  kind of like this

```
    function dynamicLayout(){ var browserWidth = getBrowserWidth();  
    // Narrow CSS rules 
if (browserWidth < 640){ changeLayout("narrow"); } 
    // Normal (default) CSS rules 
if ((browserWidth >= 640) && (browserWidth <= 960)){ changeLayout("default"); } 

    // Wide CSS rules 
if (browserWidth > 960){ changeLayout("wide"); } }
```

in your example, you have a min width property, which means if it's less then that you will have scroll bars.  if you dont want scroll bars, you can't set any static value to any layout element, so it may flex to the browser window size.

Comment: http://www.juliabailey.com/ look at this website. No matter what browser or resolution you're using box is always in. Then look at mine. I took out min-max it's still making scrollbar appear.. I think in that design they used height property somehow in a good way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height` and `max-height`, so the browser stops the zooming when reaching them. You sample's scrollbar is always visible, even when it's "empty", and that's why it doesn't jump when resizing.

Comment: visible but there is no scrolling at all you dont go down on page at all